# How to Test to cover all branchs of function casting char array to struct use Google test C language

Tags: c, googletest

I am practicing google test C. I have a bit of confusion when writing a test case for `function_1` function.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;          //4 byte
    char b;         //1 byte
    char c;         //1 byte
    char d;         //1 byte
    char arr[3];    //3 byte
}ABCXYZ;

static void function_1(char *abc)
{
    if (abc != null)
    {
    ABCXYZ *name =(ABCXYZ *)(abc + 4);
    if (name->b == 1) 
        printf("ONE");
    else if (name->b == 2)
        printf("TWO");
    else 
        printf("OTHER");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
}
```

I have written test case like this:

```
TEST(Test_function_1,abc_null)
{
    function_1(null);
}
TEST(Test_function_1,one)
{
    char arr[10]={1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
    function_1(arr);
}
TEST(Test_function_1,two)
{
    char arr[10]={2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    function_1(arr);
}
TEST(Test_function_1,other)
{
    char arr[10]={3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    function_1(arr);
}
```

But when I check result and report coverage html, it is not cover all branchs in function. How I can change test case to cover entire branchs ?
[image]

Comment: You should fill a big array with incrementing numbers, e.g. `char array[32] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};` and pass it to the function. Then modify the function to print `name->b`. That way, you'll know where `name->b` is located in the `abc` parameter.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that `function_1` violates the strict aliasing rule, and therefore has undefined behavior.

Comment: How I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the test cases but your function has a problem.

This line of code `ABCXYZ *name =(ABCXYZ *)(abc + 4);` does not help you to pass the value of the first element of the array into the field `b` of struct `name`.

So `name->b` always has some random value and in these cases the value are happened to be different to `1` and `2` so you got the `else` branch.

You need to allocate memory for `name` and then assign value of `abc[0]` to the field `b`:

```
    ABCXYZ *name = (ABCXYZ *) malloc (sizeof (ABCXYZ)); 
    name->b = abc[0];
```

p/s: This function is wierd though.

Comment: As i understand, **a** is a int variable( 4 bytes),**b** is a char variable (1 byte), so `abc +4` similar to  `name -> b`. Is it right ?

Comment: @TiếnTeoCri no, it's so messed up in that line of code. `abc+4` is the address of the 4th element in the array, you assign that address to the struct pointer `name` !

Comment: Do this to understand more `printf("address of abc %p \n", abc);` `printf("address of abc+4 %p \n", abc + 4);` `printf("address of name %p \n", name);` `printf("address of name->b %p \n", &name->b);`

Comment: I have test ok, I should set **1** or **2** or **other** at **arr[8]**.